# Use string defined type value as string

Tags: go, typedef

I have defined a type in the following way

```
type User string
```

and now I want to use a `User` value as an actual string like so

```
func SayHello(u User) string {
    return "Hello " + user + "!"
}
```

But I receive an error saying

```
cannot use "Hello " + user + "!" (type User) as type string in return argument
```

How do I use a typedef'd type as its underlying type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Golang Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability)

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to
>   T") if:
>
> - x's type is identical to T.
> - x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of    V or T is not a defined type.

Variables of named type `type User string` and unnamed type `var user string` are absolutely different.
We can check that using reflection for showing the underlying type.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    )

type User string

func main() {
    var name User = "User"
    var name2 string = "User"
    //fmt.Print(name==name2) // mismatched types User and string
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(name2))
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(name))
}
```

So check the underlying type of a variable and then type cast the type to primitive one to compare the value.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type User string

func main() {
    var u User
    fmt.Print(SayHello(u))
}

func SayHello(u User) string {
    change := string(u)
    return "Hello " + change + "!"
}
```

Check on 
[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/aK96uyxcvK0)

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic Always refer to golang specs if you find anything confusing.

Answer (score 3):

[Go does not have typedefs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity).

> Two types are either identical or different.
>
> A defined type is always different from any other type.

User is a defined type and consequently different from type string.

Since the underlying type of User is string, you can simply [convert from one type to the other](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

```
"Hello " + string(user) + "!"
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use `return "Hello " + string(user) + "!"`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`fmt.Sprintf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) without any additional conversion of your argument or concatenation of your parts of strings:

```
func SayHello(u User) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Hello %s!", u)
}
```

Even if you change your type from `string` to `struct` you still would be able to use `SayHello` if you'll implement method `func (u *User) String() string`. However such approach would also work for regular `string` conversion provided by `goofle`.

Try it at https://play.golang.org/p/XnxeOucPZdE.